# How do I list a BibTex entry for a journal article published over multiple issues?

Tags: bibtex

I'm relatively new to LaTeX and very new to BibTeX. I need to create a number of bibliography entries for journal articles that are cited as single entries, but that were published across multiple issues. For example:

Angus-Leppan, P. V. A Study of Refraction in the Lower Atmosphere. **120**, 62; **121**, 107; **122**, 166

I'm already using the natbib package if that's any use.

Comment: The same paper published in 3 different volumes? What a huge paper!

Comment: Indeed. Over 30 pages. Fortunately most of the papers in this journal are single-part ones, but there are others that span five issues. I've been looking at modern citations to the same papers (which date back to the 40s, 50s and 60s) and it seems that they only cite the last article in the series. But, given that I'm working on a deeply technical document I'd like to include the full entry if possible.

Comment: So maybe you could create 3 entries, one for each paper and cite using `\cite{foo1,foo2,foo3}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @sigur, thanks for the suggestion. My issue is that it's a single article, not three separate articles. In all of the places where I've seen it (and the others like it) referenced, it's always cited and referenced as a single item.

Comment: So, since it is a single, IMHO it is better tocite the first one, which contains the contents and all other info.

Comment: @sigur, I'm still compiling the bibliography and haven't managed to lay my hands on a copy of it yet, but I think your idea of citing the first (or last) part depending on how they're written is probably the best way to go. I had just hoped there would be a neat BibTeX trick to handle it.

Comment: I take back my comment about it being one paper. It is actually three separate papers carrying the same title. With that said it still doesn't get around the fact that I have to match an existing citation and referencing style that combines them into a single entry.

Comment: This is a problem that is not addressed well with traditional BibTeX.  Using the `biblatex` package (instead of `natbib`), there is the `@set`, which would be useful in this situation.  Unfortunately, few of the contributed styles use it (on the humanities 'side', anyway: perhaps it is used more on the science side of things).  Aside to Sigur: I don't think citing the first 'part' only is the right approach: it is unlikely that the first piece will 'know' the pagination of the subsequent articles.

Comment: @jon, thanks for the advice. I'll look at biblatex, although I have to admit I'm still coming to terms with the many LaTeX packages. In the meantime I've decided to break each paper into its separate parts and add them all to the reference list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example using `biblatex` and an entry set:

[image: Sample output]

### `bib` file

```
@Set{AL:lower,
  entryset = {AL:main,AL2,AL3},
}

@Article{AL:main,
  author =   {Angus-Leppan, P. V.},
  title =    {A Study of Refraction in the Lower Atmosphere},
  journaltitle = {Survey Review},
  year =     1961,
  volume =   120,
  pages =    62
}

@Article{AL2,
  xref = {AL:main},
  volume =   121,
  pages =    107
}

@Article{AL3,
  xref = {AL:main},
  volume =   122,
  pages =    166
}
```

### Main document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring{in}\space}}}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{set}{\entryset{%
  \ifnumequal{\thefield{entrysetcount}}{1}{}{\addsemicolon\space}}{}%
  \finentry}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{AL:lower}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a very nice solution, Andrew. Thanks!